# Convergence of sequences

Tags: convergence-divergence

Prove: If the sequence $<a_{n}>$ converges to $b\in \mathbb{R}$, then the sequence $<|a_{n} - b|>$ converges to $0$.

Since $<a_{n}>$ converges to $b\in \mathbb{R}$, denoted by

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}<a_{n}> = b$

then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a positive integer $n_{0}$ such that $n > n_{0}\Rightarrow |a_{n} - b| < \epsilon \Rightarrow b - \epsilon < a_{n} < b + \epsilon$.

So:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}<|a_{n} - b|> \   \geq  \ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}<||a_{n}| - |b|| = b - b = 0$

I am not sure if this is right, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay, but you don't need the result $a_n \to a, b_n \to b \implies a_n-b_n \to a-b$ here. Just notice that the definitions of $a_n \to b$ and $|a_n - b| \to 0$ are pratically the same. Given $\epsilon > 0$, exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $n  > n_0$ implies $|a_n - b| < \epsilon$. So $$||a_n-b| - 0| = ||a_n-b|| = |a_n-b|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: ok, even if I don't need the result is the proof ok as is?

Comment: Looking closely, no, all that $\langle$ and $\rangle$ got in my way. It is not true that $|a_n-b| = |a_n| - |b|$, so your last expression is not valid.

Comment: But $|a_{n} - b| \geq ||a_{n}| - |b||$ therefore I and use that to say as the limit goes to infinity and use the fact the $a_{n}$ converges to $b$ and this $b - b = 0$

Comment: And this states that the limit is greater than or equal to zero. Which in fact is trivial, since $|\cdot|$ only assume non-negative values.

Comment: Ok, so how do I correct my proof?

Comment: The easiest way is using the definition of $\lim_{n \to +\infty}|a_n-b|$, as have I done. Using direct manipulations with $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n=b, \lim_{n \to \infty}b=b,$ etc won't work.

Comment: are you saying your last statement in your answer above completes the proof?

Comment: Actually, my answer from "Given $\epsilon > 0$..." onwards is the entire proof..

Comment: your a boss, thanks